# is it "slideshow" or "slideshows"?

Tags: word-choice

"slideshow" or "slideshows" for a series of images/pages ?

The sentence, "Slideshows on math and programming" is correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single slideshow will consist of multiple slides, which are shown in a single presentation.

If there are multiple presentations (with different slides) than those are multiple slideshows.

Think of the word as "a show"  or "shows"  with "slide" just describing the type of show.  A show is a presentation or a performance.